# how do i use an image in java gui

Tags: java, image, user-interface, jpanel, paintcomponent

Hi im making a Gui programme using a null layout and a setBounds() method for lay out . In the programme I want 25 strings printed out on the screen in random locations . I know that i could do this with a for loop however i have been trying this to no avail.

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    for(i=0;i<25;i++){
        g.drawString("string name",Math.random()*250,Math.random()*250);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

I have been trying this and it has not been working so my question is is there some better way to do this or am i making some sort of obvious mistake.

Comment: *"using a null layout and a setBounds() method for lay out"* Don't do that, it is a path to madness.

Comment: *"has not been working"*  'Not working' is not useful to tell us what is going wrong.  What did you expect to see when it was working?  What did you see instead?  Were there any errors or exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the Math.random() part correctly try this instead:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author David
 */
public class JavaApplication142 extends JFrame {

    private int width = 300, height = 300;

    public JavaApplication142() {
        createAndShowUI();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JavaApplication142 jApp = new JavaApplication142();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        setTitle("Painting");
        setSize(width, height);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        addComponentsToContentPane(getContentPane());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComponentsToContentPane(Container contentPane) {
        Panel panel1 = new Panel();
        contentPane.add(panel1);
    }

    class Panel extends JPanel {

        private Random rand;

        public Panel() {
            rand = new Random();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                g.drawString("string name", (int) rand.nextInt(width), (int) rand.nextInt(height));
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will help to get all the strings drawn within the region of the panel, although strings with varying length might go offscreen, just add some extra code to check the length of the string and set its co-ords appropriately

Comment: Your use of `new Random()` in a loop means the 'random' values will typically be the same.  The OP's use of `Math.random()` got around that problem.  To fix your example, move the `new Random()` outside the loop, or better, declare it as a class attribute and create it once.